# Paw rest client : how to compute HMAC-SHA256 using absolute url as input

Tags: paw-app

I'm using the awesome Paw software to make Htpp requests. It has a lot of great features including the ability to compute HMAC-SHA256 signatures, unfortunately, I cannot find how to use the full url of the current request as input of this. What is the keywork to enter in the input field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Step 1**

- Right-click on the field you want to insert the hash into, pick Crypto > HMAC-SHA256
- In the *Input* field, right-click and pick Request > Request URL

**Step 2**

- You should now see a *Request URL* dynamic value in the input field, this means the HMAC-SHA256 dynamic value will take the current request's URL as its input for hash computation
- Enter your HMAC key in the Key field (tip: right-click and pick Values > Secure Value to keep your key encrypted = safer!)

[image: Compute the hash of a request URL in Paw]

---

**Old version/original answer (not up-to-date):**

There is not (yet) a Dynamic Value that returns the URL, that's a missing thing. But here's a workaround:

In the HMAC-SHA256 "Input" field, right-click and choose "Extensions" > "Custom".
You'll have a JavaScript text field, make the function return:

```
return context.getCurrentRequest().url;
```

[image: Compute the Request URL Hash in Paw]

See the [Extensions Reference](http://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Reference/Reference) for more details.