# Hashes not similar between PHP and Paw REST Client

Tags: php, hmac, sha256, paw-app

I'm building a HMAC API and I have issues testing the hashing with Paw.

On Paw I have this payload:

```
GET:/hello/world:"":9a6e30f2016370b6f2dcfb6880501d7f2305d69bout
```

and a custom HMAC-SHA256 variable (actually function [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200290/paw-rest-client-how-to-compute-hmac-sha256-using-absolute-url-as-input) that sets it in the X-Hash header.

```
X-Hash: 4Cq2yehWumDcUk1dYyfhm6qWjJVBkOCB8o12f5l0WGE=
```

In my PHP API I have the same thing:

```
GET:/hello/world:"":9a6e30f2016370b6f2dcfb6880501d7f2305d69bout
```

and used:

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $this->getPayload(), '9a6e30f2016370b6f2dcfb6880501d7f2305d69bout', false);
```

So when comparing the hashes:

```
Paw: 4Cq2yehWumDcUk1dYyfhm6qWjJVBkOCB8o12f5l0WGE=
PHP: 6961b9d1f6e986c49d963cbebd691fa68dfa59b4ce3b7f05320c2d43eae3c7c3
```

They are very different. Any idea why is that?

*Update*

Paw Code:

```
function evaluate(context){
  var loc = getLocation(context.getCurrentRequest().url);

  var payload = "";
  payload += context.getCurrentRequest().method + ':';
  payload += loc.pathname + ':';
  payload += JSON.stringify(context.getCurrentRequest().body) + ':';
    payload += "9a6e30f2016370b6f2dcfb6880501d7f2305d69bout"; // Private key
  return payload;
};

function getLocation(href) {
    var match = href.match(/^(https?\:)\/\/(([^:\/?#]*)(?:\:([0-9]+))?)(\/[^?#]*)(\?[^#]*|)(#.*|)$/);
    return match && {
        protocol: match[1],
        host: match[2],
        hostname: match[3],
        port: match[4],
        pathname: match[5],
        search: match[6],
        hash: match[7]
    }
}
```

PHP Code (with lots of comments):

```
if (strpos(strtoupper($authHeader), 'HMAC') !== 0) {
    echo 'out';
    throw new HttpForbiddenException();
}
else {
    $hmacSignature = $app->request->headers()->get('X-Hash');
    $publicKey = $app->request->headers()->get('X-Public');

    if ( empty($hmacSignature) || empty($publicKey) ) {
        echo 'out2';
        throw new HttpForbiddenException();
    }
    else {

        $this->hmacManager->setPublicKey($publicKey);
        print '$publickey = ' . $publicKey . '<br>';

        // Validate if base64_encoded or not
        if( base64_decode($hmacSignature, true) !== FALSE ) {
            $binaryString = base64_decode($hmacSignature);
            $hmacSignature = bin2hex($binaryString);
            print 'decoding ' . '<br>';
        }
        $this->hmacManager->setHmacSignature($hmacSignature);
        print '$hmacSignature = ' . $hmacSignature . '<br>';

        $this->hmacManager->setRequestMethod($app->request->getMethod());
        print 'method = ' . $app->request->getMethod() . '<br>';
        $this->hmacManager->setRequestResourceUri($app->request->getResourceUri());
        print 'uri = ' . $app->request->getResourceUri() . '<br>';

        $requestBody = $app->request()->getBody();
        if (Utils::isJson($requestBody)) {
            $requestBody = json_decode($requestBody);
        }
        $this->hmacManager->setRequestBody(json_encode($requestBody));
        print 'body = ' . json_encode($requestBody) . '<br>';

        print 'private key = ' . $this->hmacManager->getPrivateKey() . '<br>';

        $payload = '';
        $payload .= $this->hmacManager->getRequestMethod() . ":";
        $payload .= $this->hmacManager->getRequestResourceUri() . ":";
        $payload .= $this->hmacManager->getRequestBody() . ":";
        $payload .= $this->hmacManager->getPrivateKey();
        print 'PHP payload [' . $payload . ']';
        $this->hmacManager->setPayload($payload);

        $hmacValue = $this->hmacManager->generateHmac();
        $isValid = $this->hmacManager->isValid($this->hmacManager->generateHmac(), $hmacSignature);

        if ($isValid !== true) {
            echo 'out3';
            throw new HttpForbiddenException();
        }
    }
}
```

generateHmac from another class:

```
public function generateHmac()
{
    print 'Generating HMAC' . '<br>';
    $algorithm = $this->getAlgorithm();
    print 'algo ' . $algorithm . '<br>';
    $privateKey = $this->getPrivateKey();
    print 'privk ' . $privateKey . '<br>';

    if (empty($algorithm)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Algorithm must be set and not empty');
    } elseif (empty($privateKey)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Private key must be set and not empty');
    }

    print 'payload ' . $this->getPayload() . '<br>';
    $hash = hash_hmac($this->getAlgorithm(), $this->getPayload(), $this->getPrivateKey(), false);
    print 'php hasj: ' . $hash . '<br>';

    return $hash;
}
```

Finally, here's the output statements:

```
$publickey = 95f97b93560f951b4cae46c86d03d9b1a81d4ae8
decoding 
$hmacSignature = e02ab6c9e856ba60dc524d5d6327e19baa968c954190e081f28d767f99745861

method = GET
uri = /hello/world
body = ""
private key = 9a6e30f2016370b6f2dcfb6880501d7f2305d69bout
PHP payload [GET:/hello/world:"":9a6e30f2016370b6f2dcfb6880501d7f2305d69bout]

Generating HMAC
algo sha256
privk 9a6e30f2016370b6f2dcfb6880501d7f2305d69bout
payload GET:/hello/world:"":9a6e30f2016370b6f2dcfb6880501d7f2305d69bout
php hash: 6961b9d1f6e986c49d963cbebd691fa68dfa59b4ce3b7f05320c2d43eae3c7c3
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paw hash is base64 encoded while the PHP one is in hexadecimal. So decode the paw hash first:

```
$binary = base64_decode($pawHash);
$hex = bin2hex($binary);
```

And then compare this to your own hash.

Comment: Can't I do the opposite? Decode the generated hash in Paw before sending it so my API is as it is? Or perhaps detect if it's base64-encoded?

Comment: Still not working. I did like you said (and check if base64_decode (str, true) !== FALSE) to be sure it's a base64 string but it now give me this hash: e02ab6c9e856ba60dc524d5d6327e19baa968c954190e081f28d767f99745861 still very different from what I have in PHP.

Comment: It's hard to tell what could be the issue without seeing the rest of the code. It could be something wrong with the payload for example. Even a tiny difference and the hashes will look totally different.

Comment: Color me dumb, I forgot to give Paw the private key in the 'Key' field...AAAARG! @this.lau_ you still helped me greatly so I will accept your answer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

We've just added new [Base 64 to Hex conversion dynamic values](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/?q=base64), this should solve your problem.

Wrap your HMAC signature dynamic value inside the new Base 64 to Hex one, and you'll get a valid hexadecimal signature:

[image: Hexadecimal HMAC signature with Paw]

You can install this new dynamic value here: [Base 64 to Hex Dynamic Value](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/Base64ToHexDynamicValue)