# PAW Rest Client: Generating HMAC-SHA256 Signature for AWS requests

Tags: paw-app

I cannot successfully generate a signature for making AWS Requests using PAW.

Here is a link to the signature I am attempting to generate: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/HMACSignatures.html#HMACAuth_ItemsRequired

I have already searched other StackOverflow posts such as: [Paw rest client : how to compute HMAC-SHA256 using absolute url as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200290/paw-rest-client-how-to-compute-hmac-sha256-using-absolute-url-as-input)

Comment: I guess you're getting a warning (little orange flag in the top bar) saying that there's a circular dependency error? We're fixing this issue in the next version Paw 2.2.8 that should be released by next week. I'll update this thread with a good answer when it's released. Thank you!

Comment: Just installed the 2.2.8 update.  Please respond with updated answer when possible.  Thank you!

Comment: I just answered the question below, both regarding the use of SHA-256 and with a general solution for using the Amazon Product Advertising API. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your precise question about HMAC-SHA256 signatures, here's a code snippet that will work to compute this specific type of signature, returning the result Base 64 encoded in Paw (it uses the HMAC Dynamic Value programmatically):

```
function signHmac256(input, key) {
    var dv = DynamicValue("com.luckymarmot.HMACDynamicValue", {
        input: input,
        key: key,
        algorithm: 3 /* = SHA256 */,
        uppercase: false /* keep hashes lowercase */,
        encoding: 'Base64' /* encode hash data in base 64 */,
    });
    return dv.getEvaluatedString();
}
```

Otherwise, about the AWS Product Advertising API, we've made a dynamic value for it just today (which is a good opportunity for use to showcase the extension API), see [AWS Product Advertising API Auth for Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/AWSECommerceServiceDynamicValue) and the [GitHub Repository here](https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-AWSECommerceServiceDynamicValue).

To use this dynamic value, first install it through the link shared above, then you can set up all other parameters and then enter a `Signature` parameter, and set this dynamic value as its value:

[image: Use the AWS Product Advertising API in Paw HTTP Client]

Open the token to enter your AWS Secret Key (used in the HMAC signature):

[image: Use the AWS Product Advertising API in Paw HTTP Client]

Comment: This should work for all AWS signatures and not just the E-Commerce Service, correct?

Comment: I'm frankly not sure. AWS uses different auth models for all services. I know Amazon S3 is using a different one (that Paw supports natively).